# What is the path context for vaadin application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

i have prepared my ever first vaadin application by installing plugin and created vaadin project.
After build success and deployed to wildFly when try to run the application using below
localhost:port/myapp/ and localhost:port//myapp/MyUIServlet also did not work

Proj ENV details:
Servlet API 3.0
Vaadin 7.7.13

i am very new to vaadin framework, can some one please help me..?

Comment: Did you use a [Maven archetype](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/getting-started/getting-started-archetypes.html) to create your project? If so, which one?

Comment: By the way, Vaadin 7 is retired as I recall. Consider using Vaadin 8 instead, unless your deployment specifically targets [much older web browsers](https://dev.vaadin.com/wiki/Vaadin7). Or unless you really like the [Reindeer theme](https://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme) (as I did), now deprecated in 8. Otherwise, I cannot recall any reason to not use Vaadin 8. See [docs on migrating 7 to 8](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html).

Comment: Thank you Basil for info, sure i will also try that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution to this,

it works with **http:localhost/myapp/VAADIN**
i can see sample vaadin application page.